# Merge folders is not working

Tags: finder, folders, copy-paste, macos

I'm trying to merge two folders with the same name but different contents in Finder on OSX Mountain Lion.

The folder is located on my iMac and I am dragging a dropping to my External Harddrive where there is a folder with the same name.

I was getting the option to "Merge" previously but now it only shows "Replace".

I've tried holding down the option key and it still doesn't work.

If i drag it the reverse way (from external HD to my iMac) it works.

I also created a new user profile and it works fine both ways on there, so it's making me think I've changed a setting on my current profile but I can't see any options in any of the preferences.

It sounds like a little thing but it really bugs me and is an inconvenience so if anybody can help I'll be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Here I found a good discussion on the topic:

[http://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-the-mac][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/117621/how-to-merge-and-not-replace-folders-when-copying-on-the-mac

Answer (score 2):

It wont work in Mac OS if there are sub folders with the same name.

I use Deltawalker for merging folders.

http://www.deltopia.com/compare-merge-sync/macosx/